# Background image not showing up on mobile page

Tags: css

I'm trying to show different background images based off the screen size. What my CSS has is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) { body{background: url(../images/background/background_320.png) no-repeat ;} }
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) { body{background: url(../images/background/background_768.png) no-repeat ;} }
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) { body{background: url(../images/background/background_1200.png) no-repeat ;} }
```

The images show up for the large two sizes, but when I have a screen size of 320-768, no image shows up. I've verified that the file is there, but I don't know why the image isn't showing up.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: sounds like the 320px image is not found somehow, or cannot be displayed for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
body{
   background: url(../images/background/background_320.png) no-repeat ;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1199px) {
   body{ background-image: url(../images/background/background_768.png);} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
   body{ background-image: url(../images/background/background_1200.png);} 
}
```

Since you're only going to be changing the background image and not the `no-repeat` declaration, we can take it off the Media Queries for a cleaner code.

Comment: Close enough. I just had to make the 320 line: `@media only screen { body{background: url../images/background/background_320.png) no-repeat ;}}`

Comment: IMO you don't really need the `only screen` unless you don't want the background to be printed out when your user prints out the page - but most printers strip out background image / color anyways when they print?